# wp_insert_post or wp_set_post_terms do not save taxonomy, but wp_set_post_terms does

Tags: wp-insert-post

I have a litlle problem. I have a custom taxonomy 'rodzaj' with value i.ex. obrazek. I use this code to add post:

```
$postArray = array(
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author'=> get_current_user_id(),
                'post_category'=>array($catId),
                'post_title' => $_POST['titlePhoto'],
                'tax_input' => array( 'rodzaj' => array( 'obrazek') ) , 
);
```

This code adds a post but without taxonomy. I tried also this:

```
wp_set_object_terms($postId, "obrazek", 'rodzaj', false);
```

Doesn't work too.

Working code is:

```
wp_set_post_terms( $postId, array( 'obrazek'), 'rodzaj' );
```

Why first 2 functions doesn't work?

I made mistake at the begining. This is full working code:

```
$catId = get_cat_ID("Obrazki");

         $postArray = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author'=> get_current_user_id(),
            'post_category'=>array($catId),
            'post_title' => $_POST['titlePhoto'],
            'tags_input' => explode(',', $_POST['tagsPhoto'])
         );


         $postId = wp_insert_post($postArray);
         if($postId) 
         {
              wp_set_object_terms($postId, "obrazek", 'rodzaj', false);

          }
```

Still doesn't working:
wp_set_post_terms($postId, "obrazek", 'rodzaj', false);

and 
'tax_input' => array( 'rodzaj' => array( 'obrazek') ) in postArray()

Comment: hmmm your code examples are incomplete, e.g. we don't see the part where you call wp_insert_post, register your taxonomy etc etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $postId, array( 'obrazek'), 'rodzaj' );
```

`wp_set_object_terms` and `wp_set_post_terms` take the same arguments. `wp_set_post_terms` even uses wp_set_object_terms internally. The main difference being that you used an array in the one that worked, and you didn't use an array in the one that didn't work.

Comment: working code right now is: wp_set_object_terms($postId, "obrazek", 'rodzaj', false); I tried the same parameter with wp_set_post_terms but it doesn't work

Comment: Again can you provide the full code? Your function call is just 1 line, without the context provided by the surrounding code it is incredibly difficult to diagnose or debug.

Comment: Looking back at this, don't use wp_set_post_terms, just use wp_set_object_terms. Also notice my comment on the use of an array in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If your taxonomy is hierarchical, then the tax_input parameter of wp_insert_post needs an array if ids, not slugs.

```
'tax_input' => array(
  'name_of_taxonomy' => array(125) // say your term_id is 125
)
```

After doing this, you will probably have to update the term count with something like this:

```
add_action('init','reset_terms_counts', 11, 0);
function reset_terms_counts(){

    $terms_ids = get_terms(array(
      'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name'
      ,'fields' => 'ids'
      ,'hide_empty' => false
    ));

    if(is_array($terms_ids)) wp_update_term_count_now($terms_ids, 'taxonomy_name');
  }
}
```